# If the axion is discovered would it be an add on to the Standard Model?

Tags: particle-physics

Just curious to know if the axion was ever discovered would it contradict the Standard Model?  Or is it just the case that it would be add on?

Which leads one to wonder ...how do physicists decide if an add on is  worthy to be an add on since it may lead to a contradiction if the original theory does not predict it?  Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

> [The axion  is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion) hypothetical elementary particle postulated by the Peccei–Quinn theory in 1977 to resolve the [strong CP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_CP_problem) in quantum chromodynamics (QCD). If axions exist and have low mass within a specific range, they are of interest as a possible component of cold dark matter.

If you look at the [particle table of the standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), there is no elementary particle called axion. There is no contradiction, as [the theory that proposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peccei%E2%80%93Quinn_theory) it tries to formulate theoretically  why there is no CP violation in QCD. The standard model would have to be modified to accommodate the axion, if it is found by the experiments.

Comment: I have trouble understanding  what "accommodate" means.  Does this mean the mathematics would have to be re formulated or a new mathematics discovered to predict the axion OR does  "add on" just mean an extra side note to the theory like a " oh by the way there are these extra particles".  I  have seen this in an article where scientists wand to "add on" to the standard model to explain all the unknown observations as if they were foot notes ...or do they mean to change the math so the particle  is predicted?  now you see my confusion?

Comment: It may mean new symmetries added to the SM ,or as with neutrino masses to accept violations see : https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2669 . one modifies the maths of the lagrangian of the SM